# InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13] for .csv file

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi

I am trying to read a .csv file created from the script which has the results of query run on DB. Now this file is created every time I run the query. While trying to get `XSSFWorkbook` object for it the following exception occurs:

> ```
> org.apache.poi.POIXMLException:
> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: 
> Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
> ```

Now I have another csv file created earlier manually and when I try to get  an `XSSFWorkbook` object for that it works fine.
 I am trying to compare the content of these two files, But I am not able to read both the files. The one created in the script throws the above exception.

Why does that happen and how can I get an `XSSFWorkbook` for the first .csv?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: This code generates the csv file. results is a ResultSet from the query String Actualcsv = csvpath + "_Results.csv";                                       File file= new File (Actualcsv);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(fw);
writer.writeAll(results, true);
writer.close();

Comment: The following code is to access the file Result.csv                                                                                           
FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(new File("path\\Results.csv"));
FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream(new    File("path\\ENT12355_Expected.csv"));

// Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
 XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file1);
 XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file2);

Comment: Could you try using HSSFWorkbook.

Comment: for CSV files have to use XSSFWorkbook. we get the message: You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)

Comment: Please have a look at this code:                                                       
File file= new File ("path\\ENT12355_Results.csv");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(fw);
writer.writeNext(compareValue);
writer.close();
FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(new File(
 "path\\ENT12355_Results.csv"));
FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream(new File(
"path\\ENT12355_Expected.csv"));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file2);
XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file1);                Gives the same exception as above.

Comment: `XSSFWorkbook` is used to read `.xlsx` files. Why on earth are you trying to read a CSV file with it?

Comment: I am able to read a already created CSV file. There are no issues there. I can read it as a xl sheet and get values with respect to the column headers. The one created by CSVWriter fails to open, the format does not match and throws the exception.